# when do the principle components of PCA form a basis for the dataset?

Tags: math, statistics, linear-algebra, data-science, pca

Suppose I do a PCA on a dataset and get k principles components that explains 100% of the total variance of the dataset.

We can say any observation from the dataset can be reconstructed by the mean plus a linear combination of all principle components.

When I do analysis on different datasets, I noticed sometimes observations can be reconstructed by a linear combination of the principle components alone(v1,v2,..,vk) without using the mean even though the observations do not have a zero mean.

This means the mean of the observations can be reconstructed using the linear combination of the principle components(v1,v2,..,vk) as well. It seems this happens when the observations are actually linear combinations of a different set of vectors(x1,x2,...,xk).

For a dataset containing vectors belonging to a vector space spanned by some vector x1,x2,...xk, if I do PCA on this dataset, will the principle components always be able to reconstruct the observations in the dataset alone without adding the mean? It feels like PC find an orthogonal basis for this dataset, but why?

Comment: Yes. Because in those cases, the global origin belongs to the subspace generated by PCA. This assumes that this applies to all possible subspaces (if they are not unique). Anyway, you might have more luck at [stats.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.